# WordPress Insert Data from a text file to custom table

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert data to a custom table using plugin activation hook `register_activation_hook`so when the plugin active the database and its data will insert automatically. The data is in a text file in plugin directory. When I active the plugin database created but no the insert. I thing I did mistake to read the txt file. can someone help me to solve this?

I have a list of data into a text file format like

```
123|Jhon Doe
124|Michel Muller
125|Jems Curter
126|Miss Weedy
127|Burgel Heigen
```

I am trying to import them into a wordpress database but failed.

bellow is my code.

```
//creating db table 
function sbl_employee_create_db() {

    global $wpdb;

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $table_employee  = $wpdb->prefix . 'sbl_employee';
    $table_br_name   = $wpdb->prefix . 'sbl_br_name';



    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_br_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        br_code int(5) NOT NULL,
        br_name varchar(220) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}


//function to insert branch data to database
function insert_brcode_name(){
    global $wpdb;
    $textCnt   = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."data.txt";
    $file = fopen($textCnt, 'r');

    $arrfields = explode('|', $file);

    $br_code =  $arrfields[0]; 
    $br_name =  $arrfields[1]; 


    $data = array(
                    'br_code'           => $br_code,
                    'br_name'           => $br_name,
                   );

        //format values: %s as string; %d as integer
        $format = array(
            '%s', '%d'
          );
        $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data, $format );

}

//do action when plugin active
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'sbl_employee_create_db' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'insert_brcode_name' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the `insert_brcode_name()` function:

- Assuming the file was successfully opened (via [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)), `$file` is actually a file pointer resource and not a `string`. So `$arrfields = explode('|', $file);` won't work — it won't give you the result that you expected (and PHP will throw a warning).
- Secondly, the `$format` should be `array( '%d', '%s' )` and not `array( '%s', '%d' )`, because in the `$data` array, the first item is `br_code` (integer/`int`) and the second item is `br_name` (string/`varchar`). *So* the first item in `$format` is for the first item in `$data`; the second item in `$format` is for the second item in `$data`; and so on for other items.
- `$tablename` is not defined; which I believe is the `$wpdb->prefix . 'sbl_br_name'` table.

So here's the `insert_brcode_name()` *without* the above issues: (**tried and tested** working)

```
function insert_brcode_name(){
    $textCnt = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "data.txt";
    $file = @fopen($textCnt, 'r');

    // Make sure that it's a valid file pointer resource.
    if ( ! $file ) {
        return false;
    }

    global $wpdb;
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'sbl_br_name';

    // Reads each line in the file.
    while ( ! feof( $file ) ) {
        $line = fgets( $file );
        $arrfields = explode('|', $line);

        // Ignores invalid entries..
        if ( count( $arrfields ) < 2 ) {
            continue;
        }

        $br_code = $arrfields[0];
        $br_name = $arrfields[1];
        //echo $br_code . '|' . $br_name . '<br>';

        $data = array(
            'br_code' => $br_code,
            'br_name' => $br_name,
        );

        //format values: %s as string; %d as integer
        $format = array(
            '%d', // Format of `br_code`
            '%s', // Format of `br_name`
        );

        $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data, $format );
    }

    fclose( $file );
}
```

*Note: The code was re-indented for clarity. There were also minor changes, in addition to the major fixes.*